# Fix outliers in pandas by calculating z - scores

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Here's a mock DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,5,8,4,9,3,800,600, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I'd like to calculate the z-score to detect outliers and substitute the rows with mean value.

Here's my attempt:

```
df['col1'] = np.where(np.abs(stats.zscore(df['col1'])) < 3, df['col1'].mean(),df['col1'])
```

This didn't work, outliers are still in there.

Comment: It work for me , please check again

Comment: @BENY updated the question, I have `NaNs` in pandas series.

Answer (score 0):

IN your case you can `dropna` , then assign back

```
s = df.col1.dropna()
out = np.where(np.abs(stats.zscore(s)) < 3, s.mean(),s)
df.loc[df.col1.notna(),'col1'] = out
```